# options for TVOS E-Commerce

Tags: tvos, applepay, applepayjs

I am developing an E-Commerce app that will allow users to buy meals from our partners.

Wondering what are the options for the checking out?

I know that TVOS doesn't have Apple Pay, but I am wondering if we can do it with users' iPhone, just like how we can do password autofill from iPhone?

I am also thinking about sending a push notification from the Apple TV to iPhone, wondering if it can be done too.

I was trying with other buttons like paypal and visa check out, but I don't think apple tv has a webbrowser, nor the script works in TVML/TVJS.

wondering if there are some existing options I can use?